# Bracha Shehechiyanu on a diamond ring?

Tags: blessing, wedding, shehecheyanu

I was always under the impression that a Kallah that receives a diamond ring  makes the Bracha Shehechiyanu on it. [Igros Moshe, Evan HaEzer 4:84](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14678&st=&pgnum=149) seems to say that the Kallah should make the Bracha "Hatov V'Hamaitiv". I recently came across [this article from Rabbi Kaganoff](http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=12847) where he quotes Halichos Shlomo that a Kallah should not recite Shehechiyanu on gifts presented for the engagement or wedding plans. Since this Sefer is not available online I was wondering what the reasons are not to recite the Bracha?

> Above, I quoted the shaylah asked by a kallah: Do I recite
>   shehechiyanu when my choson gives me the engagement ring and when my
>   future mother-in-law presents me with my candlesticks?
>
> I mentioned above that some have the custom that one does not recite
>   shehechiyanu on new items other than clothes. Although most poskim
>   disagree with this conclusion, others cite other reasons why one
>   should not recite shehechiyanu on gifts presented as part of the
>   engagements and wedding plans (see Halichos Shelomoh 23:15). Since the
>   matter is disputed, whether a kallah should recite shehechiyanu on her
>   diamond ring or her candlesticks is something that she should ask her
>   Rav.

Comment: R Moshe isn't sure about hTvhM. He says he's going to double check. (Seemingly his debate is between hTvhM and Shehechiyanu, but definitely something.)

Comment: @DoubleAA: That is why I wrote "seems to say".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion given (footnote 70 there) is דהוי כחוב בין המחותנים that it's like an obligation between the parents. In other words, the bride and groom aren't receiving these gifts as "gifts" but as payments due to them as part of the (implicit) wedding agreement that the parents are bound to. (He doesn't find this argument fully convincing, but mentions it.)

Comment: I find it interesting that Rabbi Kaganoff would say it is disputed if that is the only reason. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @GershonGold There's the additional factor which you mentioned of "some have the custom that one does not recite shehechiyanu on new items other than clothes" which compounds the issue. (I'm not sure why they all assume jewelry isn't clothing.)